# Piwik not recording site visits on remote server

Tags: analytics, traffic, webserver, matomo

I have two different web servers at the moment:

- Webserver 1 is hosting `www.example.com`, this webserver hosts just basic website files, no databases or anything extra, just the html files. The pages display correctly on this server.
- Webserver 2 is hosting the Piwik install and currently doesn't have a domain name pointed at it, (e.g., `127.0.0.16/~username/analytics/piwik`). I'm able to log in and view the Piwik dashboard and settings page.

The problem is that Piwik isn't recording any visits and I know that visitors are going to the site, and I know I've included the correct tracking code in the headers of the HTML pages I'm trying to track.

**My Question is:** Is there something I might be missing, such as a setting? What test or common things can I double check? What info would be of use towards finding and fixing this problem?

Comment: Perhaps there is a setting someone's familiar with, or they've run into this problem before. It might also be related to not using a domain name. I'd suggest confirming the visits in your access logs, and check for errors in the errors log.

Comment: Can you check if the following issue is related to yours? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105782/piwik-not-recording-visits-on-vps-server-accessible-through-11-nat-conversion

Comment: @user247471 the issue with my piwik if I remember correctly was that instead of using a FQDN I was using the IP address. Which should have still worked but for what ever reason it wasn't. www.Example.com/piwik/path/to/piwik/counter instead of 192.0.0.1/piwik/path/to/counter

Answer (score 1):

I observed a similar issue between a live server and the new server I am planning to migrate to.

I access the latter either through its IP address or by modifying my local /etc/hosts file. The piwik install on that one doesn't record any visits.

I also observed that the visits I make to the new server are recorded to the old (live server's) piwik installation, probably because I used the same name/credentials for the databases.